# How do I create Hebrew page numbers in Scribus?

Tags: scribus

I am trying to create a Hebrew publication, and would like to know how I can number the pages with Hebrew characters, which correspond with numbers.
Microsoft word already has this feature, and I have created a list of digit-letter substitutions, but I am not a developer and cannot contribute to the program itself.
How can I go about doing this, either by inspiring someone to add this feature to the program, or by fiddling around with my own copy of Scribus?

Answer (score 2):

A very recent patch has provided the support for Hebrew *counters* in Scribus.

You will need Scribus 1.5.5 or a snapshot that is newer than May 1st 2019:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/scribus/files/scribus-svn/1.5.5.svn/

You can of course compile the latest Scribus by getting it from

https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus

or

svn://scribus.net/trunk/Scribus scribus

and you will get the patch in there.

Comment: Did you mean "a snapshot that is later than May 1st" or was the feature removed again?

Comment: yes, sorry, "newer"! (i've corrected my answer)